# Invalid token with Joomla custom component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm building a custom Joomla component and I added this to my form in my template (default.php) file (it is using a HTTP POST):

```
echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); //add hidden token field to prevent CSRF vulnerability
```

Then I check the token in my controller with:

```
JRequest::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
```

But no matter what I do I get an Invalid Token. I have verified that a hidden type with a token is created in my form when I view sources on the html page. I also verified, in the controller, the value of the token is the same:

```
print_r(JUtility::getToken());
```

So if the token is the same value, why on earth is it exiting with an Invalid Token message?

**EDIT:** There is a key piece I failed to mention. My form is processed with jquery ajax in a separate js file that is added in my view.html.php. This is what the ajax POST looks like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw',
    data: {checkedarray:checked},
    success: function(data){
               //delete row
    }
});
```

The controller processes this:

```
function deletevideos()
{

    $video_list = JRequest::getVar('checkedarray', 0, 'post', 'array');
    //print_r(JUtility::getToken());
    JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );     

    $model = &$this->getModel();
    return $model->setDeleteVideos($video_list);
}
```

This then goes to the model that does the DB update. I saw this old [post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1464422) that might be relevant. It is not clear to me how/where I generate the token and where/how I validate that token. The post seems quite involved as it checks against users as well which I don't think is needed in my case. Or maybe I misunderstand?

**EDIT #2**

Okay so the token is missing and I need to pass it into my js file. So I thought I could add this to my view.html.php:

```
    $addtoken = JUtility::getToken();
    $addtokenjs = 'jQuery(function() {
                    var token="'.$addtoken.'";
                    });';
    $doc->addScriptDeclaration( $addtokenjs );
    $doc->addScript(JURI::base()."components/com_recordings/js/recordings.js");
```

I have to put this in the document ready function because apparently addScriptDeclaration does not put anything ahead of my recordings.js file. Then pass the token into the `ajax` call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw'+token+'=1',
    data: {checkedarray:checked},
    success: function(data){
               //delete row
    }
});
```

Apparently I'm not doing this right as I get this error: `ReferenceError: token is not defined`.

Comment: Is your form being submitted via HTTP GET or via POST?

Comment: @Jim DeLaHunt It is HTTP POST

Comment: @Tom:I have updated the answer.Have a look and let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem that you are passing token value in the ajax request.And that's why you are getting this error.

You can -
1) append token to the url like this

```
url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw&'. JUtility::getToken() .'=1'
```

2) Or send the whole form using [Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

**EDIT 2:-**
 You can create a function called getToken like this-

```
 $addtokenjs = 'function getToken() {
                    var token="'.$addtoken.'";
                    return token;
                    };';
```

And in url instead of calling `token` you can call `getToken()`

```
url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw'+getToken()+'=1'
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Adding as a function worked around the problem of `addScriptDeclaration` js code not applying in the right order when you use `addScript`. Also I had to use `JSession::checkToken('request') or jexit( JText::_( 'Invalid Token' ) );` (or JRequest instead of JSession). Only if you put `request` will it work for some reason. This makes my code work at least but I'm having a problem testing to verify that an Invalid token error gets thrown...I guess I'll leave that for my next SO question =\

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
JSession::checkToken() or die( JText::_( 'Invalid Token' ) );
```

rather than JRequest. The reason I like JSession more is because it guarentees Joomla 2.5/3.0 compatibility without having to think about JRequest being deprecated. In Joomla 2.5 the function uses JRequest and in 3.0 uses JInput.

---

**EDIT**

For the AJAX ou actually need to pass the data across with the `POST`. Your data is currently just going to be the `checkedarray:checked` i.e. the checked data and NOT the token in the AJAX request. You'll need to pass the data across with serialize if you wish to use the `POST` method. However note that serialize will place the data in the URL anyhow. You can then process this token with

```
// Check for request forgeries using one of either JRequest of JSession
JRequest::checkToken( 'get' ) or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );
//Alternative
JSession::checkToken( 'get' ) or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );
```

Just for completelness the link you have given uses the GET method. In that he's passed across the username (in his case) and the token in the URL as you can see on the third line of his AJAX function

```
function check_username(username, token) {
  var url = 'index.php?option=com_user&task=check_user';
  data = 'username=' + username + '&' + token;     //TOKEN INSERTED INTO URL HERE
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(xml) {
    var result = $(xml).find('response').text();
    if (result == 'found') {
       alert( 'Please select a different username, ' + username + ' already exists' );
   }
   }
  }); // ajax
}
```

and then after this is it is trivial to process just using

```
// Check for request forgeries using one of either JRequest of JSession
JRequest::checkToken( 'get' ) or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );
//Alternative
JSession::checkToken( 'get' ) or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );
```

Either way its probably going to involve some tweaking to your model - as your passing across more than 1 variable - although it shouldn't be hard to do. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the form data is submitted as `$_GET`

```
JRequest::checkToken('get') or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );;
```

If the form data is submitted as `$_POST`

```
JRequest::checkToken('post') or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );;
```

Else you can use below which is preferred

```
JRequest::checkToken('request') or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );
```

[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms)

Comment: Thanks for looking but according to the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JRequest::checkToken/11.1), post is default (which I'm using). I tried this anyways and no luck. For the last one I tried that as well and it didn't work either (I assume you mean `JRequest` and not `Request` but tried both, just in case). I believe `request` just covers both post and get. Any other ideas?

Comment: Typo It should be JRequest. By the way attach action="index.php?<?php echo JUtility::getToken()?>=1" to your form as well and see. You know sometimes Joomla does weird stuff. let me know what happens.

Comment: I'm starting to see a key piece of the puzzle that I failed to mention. The form is processed with a jquery AJAX post request. I came across this [post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1464422) which might apply...although quite old. Any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem with your initial code is that you are not passing the token to the controller.

`data: {checkedarray:checked}` probably contains just an array of IDs you want to delete.

Irfan version is the easiest to implement and it should work. I've managed to make it work.

Here is a [gist with the working code](https://gist.github.com/4588583) (please note that this is not production ready code, it's just to test the token problem). But I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, still struggling with the fact that my jquery ajax function is in a separate js file so I can't use php here. I need to pass the token to it somehow...see updated post.

Comment: Well, you are not far away, just need to add something like: `data: {checkedarray:checked, token:token}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case of future use: On Joomla! 3.x `JUtility::getToken()` has been replaced with `JSession::getFormToken()`.

See here: http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JSession.html#method_getFormToken